# I can come and go as one scroll with a conditional

Tags: css, scroll

everyone, excuse my language I speak Spanish and I use google translator

I have a question I can appear and disappear as one scroll depending on the size of the table for example when the table arrives at a height of 300px, visible display scroll in css o java

How I can do that?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Claro que si, pero no css. Eso es un ejemplo con jQuery (sorry for my Spanish):

Sure you can, but not with css. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
if ($('#table_id').css('height') >= 300) {
    $('#scroll_id').show();
else
    $('#scroll_id').hide();
```